# Store AWS or Facebook secret key into bash**file for security reason?

Tags: amazon-web-services, facebook

I remember being told to store AWS key into a `bash**file` (something named like that, can't remember exactly) for security reason, but now I forgot how to access that `bash**file`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be **~/.bash_profile**. Open a terminal window and type.

```
vi ~/.bash_profile.
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent committing sensitive application keys/data to your code, and to provide key access to programs, you should store app keys/sensitive information in environment variables. Environment variables are similar to variables in computer programs, except they exist system-wide in Linux and Windows.

In Linux, you can store those keys in the ~/.bash_profile, so they are available in the environment to command line programs.

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

in that file, add the following:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID= *ACCESS_KEY*
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY= *SECRET_KEY*
```

Once saved, you’ll need to **source** it for the environment variable to work in your current session:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

In any new session, the environment variables will be loaded automatically.

Please note there are new and more preferred ways to store AWS credentials.

> The AWS SDK team has recently made some changes that make it more
>   convenient, more consistent, and easier to specify credentials for the
>   SDKs in a more secure way.

Instead of keeping AWS credentials in environment variables, you can now put credentials into a single file that’s in a central location. The default location is this:

```
~/.aws/credentials (Linux/Mac)
```

See https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/a-new-and-standardized-way-to-manage-credentials-in-the-aws-sdks/

Comment: Thank you very much for the details info I really appreciate it!